# How to use generated variables from one job in jenkins build flow and utilize those into next job in the same jenkins build flow

Tags: dynamic, environment-variables, inject, post-build-event, jenkins-build-flow

I have 3 jobs configured on jenkins build flow and the desired activity is to get dynamic variables resulted from post-build task of b1 to b2 and variables of b2 to b3 and so on so forth.

```
list = ["foo", "bar"]

b1 = build("ExecuteJob1", param1: list[idx])
b2 = build("ExecuteJob2", param1: <some dynamic variable from b1>)
b3 = build("ExecuteJob3", param1: <some dynamic variable from b2>, param2: some dynamic variable from b1)
```

As specified above, there are dynamic variables generated by each previous job (as a part of post build action - I'm using [description setter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin) plugin in one instance to generate one dynamic variable and other I want *BUILD_URL* of b1 to be used in b3)

In order to accomplish this, I came across a post present in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508444/jenkins-build-flow-how-to-pass-a-variable-from-one-job-to-another) and used [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin). Using this I performed the following -

1. I created a job (envInj) in order to inject those dynamic variables into environment
2. I used that envInj job as post-condition job for b1 and given some time out between b1 and b2 to make sure post-condition job executes before b2 begins.
3. This actually injects the variables required to environment (if checked in console logs as well as environment variables of envInj job).

But the issue I am facing is that those newly injected variables are not available for b2 to access and the same case for b3.

So, is there any option to get those b1 variables to b2 (so on and so forth) or is there any better way to achieve the desired ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution for the above question, as specified by @Dave Bacher in the above link,

1. I dumped the parameters to a file using batch script in [Post Build Task](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task) plugin.
2. This file was injected back to environment using [EvnInj plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin).
3. This allowed me to access those parameters in other jobs of build flow

   ```
   b1 = build("ExecuteJob1", param1: list[idx])
   b2 = build("ExecuteJob2", param1: b1.dynamicVariableX)
   b3 = build("ExecuteJob3", param1: b1.dynamicVariableY, param2:nb2.dynamicVariableZ)
   ```

This works perfectly allowing to access dynamic variables through environment